# How to use generics in Haskell

Tags: generics, haskell

I'm trying to wrap my head around generics in Haskell. My issue is I created a concatenate function that takes a list of Strings and returns a giant string.

```
concatenate:: [String] -> String
concatenate xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ x) [] xs
```

But now I'd like instead of a list of strings, use a list of anything. This can be strings, can be ints. So say

```
concatenate ["Phil", "is"]
```

generates "Philis" while

```
concatenate [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

generates [1,2,3,4].

I've found that

```
concatenate:: [a] -> a
concatenate xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ x) [] xs
```

does not work and I'm not sure why. Isn't the way haskell works, whatever type a is, the output is a as well? Or is the issue with the second half not allowing it to work as a function for all types?

Comment: When you aren't sure why (and when you ask for help on SO) it is best to read and relay the error message which clearly says there is a type error.

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that, the error message reads:

`Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
In the first argument of '(++)', namely 'acc'
In the expression: acc ++ x
In the first argument of 'foldl', namely '(\ acc x -> acc ++ x)'`

This is after I've replaced [a] with [[a]] with the help of @Pubby 's useful tidbit on String. 

Is it trying to say that ++ won't work with the type a? Or that it's too general and ++ only works with lists? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: With Pubby's fix to the type signature your code is fine.  If you are still getting errors then you are using a broken setup or you have made some other change.  Did you remember to change the RESULT `a` to `[a]` as Pubby pointed out?

Comment: Oh, and just to keep the terminology straight - this is just polymorphism.  Generics is a different concept.

Comment: Ah! I didn't. I left it as [[a]] -> a. Thanks so much for the catch!

Comment: It is indeed, I remember the professor comparing it to generics in Java and forgot the term for it in Haskell, thanks a lot for the help Thomas.

Comment: Note that using a left fold for concatenating is inefficient. You should - like the `Prelude` (well, modulo the fusion `{-# RULES #-}`) - use a right fold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that `String` is an alias for `[Char]`.

What you really intended was this:

```
concatenate:: [[a]] -> [a]
```